# WCF Response is not signed or encrypted

Tags: wcf

I am hosting a WCF service, I get the request and can unsigned and uncrypted it without a problem with custombindings, but why does my response is not automatically siged and encrypted??? any one help?

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="DutyTravelSOAP12Binding">
      <transactionFlow transactionProtocol="WSAtomicTransaction11"/>
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
          messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15" allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
          enableUnsecuredResponse="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
          requireDerivedKeys="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" includeTimestamp="False"
          keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
          messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
          allowInsecureTransport="false">
        <localClientSettings detectReplays="false" maxClockSkew="00:25:00"
            replayWindow="00:25:00" sessionKeyRolloverInterval="00:25:00"
            timestampValidityDuration="00:25:00" />
        <localServiceSettings detectReplays="false" />
        <secureConversationBootstrap allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" requireDerivedKeys="true"
            enableUnsecuredResponse="false" securityHeaderLayout="Lax" keyEntropyMode="CombinedEntropy"
            includeTimestamp="False" allowInsecureTransport="false"
            requireSignatureConfirmation="true" authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
            messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"  defaultAlgorithmSuite ="Basic128Rsa15"
            messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
          <localClientSettings detectReplays="true"/>
          <localServiceSettings detectReplays="true"/>
        </secureConversationBootstrap>
      </security>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
        realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

This is my custom bindings

Comment: I would start with setting this `enableUnsecuredResponse` to `false`.

Comment: Btw. why do you have so huge configuration where half of settings has either default values or is not used at all? Also how did you find that response is not secured?

Comment: Maybe you can point me to those values which are defaults and not used at all.. i might remove them.

Comment: Client using the service getting error "Security missing"

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The textMessageEncoding element usually goes *after* the security element ...